# A word for people that have the same characteristics

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there any word or combination of two words that describes two persons with the same characteristics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're open to idioms, you could say that these people are [**cut from the same cloth**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cut-from-the-same-cloth?q=cut%20from%20the%20same%20cloth).

> Of the same nature; similar:
>
> *don’t assume all women are cut from the same cloth*

Or they're [**like (two) peas in a pod**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/like-peas-or-two-peas-in-a-pod?q=peas%20in%20a%20pod)

> So similar as to be indistinguishable or nearly so:
>
> *they were like two peas in a pod, both with the same high cheekbones and hairline*

Answer (score 2):

You could use similar or analogous.

Comment: +1 for similar. -1 for analogous.

Comment: +1....though brains and computers are also often considered analogous”

Answer (score 0):

[Alike](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/alike)

> (Of two or more subjects) similar to each other

*The brothers were very much alike*

Answer (score 0):

[Dead Ringer](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/dead+ringer) (for someone/something)

Comment: Also *doppelganger*